# Conduit.simpleHttp - perform a request supplied with headers and data

Tags: python, haskell, networking

I have a simple application which sends an HTTP(s) request and print the data returned:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)

simpleHttp "http://example.com" >>= B.putStr
```

How do I supply the request with the headers? Or to be more concrete, how do I make the request below (written in Python) in Haskell?

```
requests.post('https://some-url.com',data=json.dumps({"aaa":"BBBCCCDDD"}), headers={"content-type":"application/json"})
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about this http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-1.2.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html

Comment: The `http` and `httpLbs` functions described immediately below `simpleHttp` take an argument of type `Request` which holds all that data.

Comment: @LeifGrele simpleHTTP itself doesn't allow to set the headers and data. And I can't figure out how to go with http and httpLbs. Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the docs for `Request`:

> The constructor for this data type is not exposed. Instead, you should
>   use either the def method to retrieve a default instance, or `parseUrl`
>   to construct from a URL, and then **use the records below to make
>   modifications**.

So you can configure request using a number of record names. In your case you need `requestHeaders` and `requestBody`. Here is an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

main :: IO ()
main = do
  request <- parseUrl "http://example.com"
  res <- withManager $ httpLbs $ configureRequest request
  print res
  where
  configureRequest r = r {
    method = methodPost,
    requestHeaders = ("content-type", "application/json") : requestHeaders r,
    requestBody = RequestBodyLBS (Aeson.encode $ Map.fromList [("aaa" :: Text, "BBBCCSDDD" :: Text)])
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the server returns "invalid arguments" whereas the python script works fine.

Comment: You probably should set http method. The default one is "GET" IIRC. Also you can use wireshark or tcpdump to debug the issue. I don't know `python`, so I don't know what is the difference between python and haskell version.